# Python - Create An Empty Pandas DataFrame and Populate From Another DataFrame Using a For Loop

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Using: Python 2.7 and Pandas 0.11.0 on Mac OSX Lion

I'm trying to create an empty `DataFrame` and then populate it from another dataframe, based on a `for loop`.

I have found that when I construct the `DataFrame` and then use the `for loop` as follows:

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
for item in cols_to_keep:
    if item not in dummies:
        data = data.join(df[item])
```

Results in an empty `DataFrame`, but with the headers of the appropriate columns to be added from the other `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you are using join incorrectly.

You can use a list comprehension to restrict the DataFrame to the columns you want:

```
df[[col for col in cols_to_keep if col not in dummies]]
```

Answer (score 2):

What about just creating a new frame based off of the columns you know you want to keep, instead of creating an empty one first?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(5),
                    'b':np.random.randn(5),
                    'c':np.random.randn(5),
                    'd':np.random.randn(5)})
cols_to_keep = ['a', 'c', 'd']
dummies = ['d']
not_dummies = [x for x in cols_to_keep if x not in dummies]
data = df[not_dummies]
data

          a         c
0  2.288460  0.698057
1  0.097110 -0.110896
2  1.075598 -0.632659
3 -0.120013 -2.185709
4 -0.099343  1.627839
```